# Magento 2 : Dynamic PDF and image attachement with order email

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email, order-email, attachment

I need to attach PDF and images with order email. I have dynamic PDF and image path which is stored in `quote_item` table. I have debugged code to attach image/PDF to order email.

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\MailTransportBuilder"></preference>
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\SenderBuilder"/>


<?php

namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail;

class MailTransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addPdfAttachment($fileContent, $filename)
    {
        if ($fileContent) {
            $this->message->createAttachment(
                $fileContent,
                'application/pdf',
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                $filename
            );

            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function addImageAttachment($fileContent, $filename)
    {
        if ($fileContent) {
            $this->message->createAttachment(
                $fileContent,
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                $filename
            );

            return $this;
        }
    }

}


<?php
/**
 * @author     Kristof Ringleff
 * @package    Fooman_EmailAttachments
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 Fooman Limited (http://www.fooman.co.nz)
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var Template
     */
    protected $templateContainer;

    /**
     * @var IdentityInterface
     */
    protected $identityContainer;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     * @param IdentityInterface $identityContainer
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
        $this->identityContainer = $identityContainer;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and send email message
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $this->transportBuilder->addPdfAttachment(file_get_contents($data),$data);

        parent::send();
    }


}
```

How can I inject order object in SenderBuilder class.

Comment: You should add more details to your question, add your related code, just offering bounty won't get you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research, I have found the way we can attach a dynamic image and PDF to order email. Kindly follow below steps to attach images to order email.

Step 1:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\MailTransportBuilder"></preference>
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\SenderBuilder"/>
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\Sender\OrderSender"/>
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template" type="vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\Container\Template"/>
```

Step 2:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail;

class MailTransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addPdfAttachment($fileContent, $filename)
    {
        if ($fileContent) {
            $this->message->createAttachment(
                $fileContent,
                'application/pdf',
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                $filename
            );

            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function addImageAttachment($fileContent, $filename)
    {
        if ($fileContent) {
            $this->message->createAttachment(
                $fileContent,
                \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                $filename
            );

            return $this;
        }
    }

}
```

Step 3:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author     Kristof Ringleff
 * @package    Fooman_EmailAttachments
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 Fooman Limited (http://www.fooman.co.nz)
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail;


class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{

    /**
     * Prepare and send email message
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $ImageList = $this->templateContainer->getImageList();
        $PdfList = $this->templateContainer->getPdfList();

        if(is_array($ImageList)){              
                foreach ($ImageList as $key => $data) {
                        $this->transportBuilder->addImageAttachment(file_get_contents($data),$data);
                }
        }

        if(is_array($PdfList)){
                foreach ($PdfList as $key => $data) {
                        $this->transportBuilder->addPdfAttachment(file_get_contents($data),$data);
                }
        }

        parent::send();
    }


}
```

Step 4:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author     Kristof Ringleff
 * @package    Fooman_EmailAttachments
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 Fooman Limited (http://www.fooman.co.nz)
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\Sender;


class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
    /**
     * @var \Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\AttachmentContainerInterface
     */
    protected $templateContainer;
     protected $_designerhelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template $templateContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
    ) {
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;

        parent::__construct(
            $this->templateContainer,
            $identityContainer,
            $senderBuilderFactory,
            $logger,
            $addressRenderer,
            $paymentHelper,
            $orderResource,
            $globalConfig,
            $eventManager
        );
      /*  $this->attachmentContainer = $attachmentContainer;*/
    }

    public function send(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $IncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        $imageData = array();
        $pdfData = array();

        foreach ($items as $item) {

            if($item->getFilename() && $item->getDocumentId())
            {          
                       $imageData[] = $item->getImagePath();
                       $pdfData[] = $item->getPdfPath();
             }
        }

        if(count($pdfData) > 0){
                $this->templateContainer->setPdfList($pdfData);            
        }

        if(count($imageData) > 0){
                $this->templateContainer->setImageList($imageData);            
        }



        return parent::send($order, $forceSyncMode);
    }
}
```

Step 5

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\moduleName\Model\Mail\Container;

class Template extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $pdfAttach;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $imageAttach;

    public function setPdfList(array $pdfList)
    {
        $this->pdfAttach = $pdfList;
    }

    public function getPdfList()
    {
        return $this->pdfAttach;
    }

    public function setImageList(array $imageList)
    {
        $this->imageAttach = $imageList;
    }

    public function getImageList()
    {
        return $this->imageAttach;
    }


}
```

Comment: How can we attached file in custom email  magento 2.3 ? because its using  zendframework 2

Comment: How can i attach a generated PDF file.for eg on success page i have written a function to generate a Pdf file using my order id and that file is getting save with the name of order id so how can i attach that dynamic file with email

Answer (score 2):

You can add attechement by preference also
then add to etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Vendor\Module\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder"
                type="\Vendor\ModuleMagento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Now you can use addAttachment() throughout your site.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder 
    extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename    = null
    ) {
        $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will send order email only or all email types (invoice, credit memo, ...)?

Comment: Not working in the latest version of Magento 2.4.2

Comment: This will just expose an "addAttachment" method for the TransportBuilder, that newer versions of Magento2 no longer have. It won't actually generate or attach any PDFs or images to the email, just give you the tools to do it, for example in a DI plugin or in an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's default email sending class `TransportBuilder` does not by default provides attachments in mail, but you can do it manually by overriding and using Zend framework integrated into Magento.

Here is a blog explaining the same - 
https://webkul.com/blog/attach-pdf-file-magento-2-email/

Comment: Not working in the latest version of Magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

To send PDF attachment in magento 2.3 in _transportBuilder , Below is the code..this will definitely  works:

```
$transport = $_transportBuilder-setTemplateIdentifier(20)
-setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
-setTemplateVars($templateVars)
-setFrom($from)
-addTo($vendor_email)
-getTransport();

$html= $transport-getMessage()-getBody()-generateMessage();       
$bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part($html); $bodyMessage-type =
'text/html';
$attachment=$_transportBuilder-addAttachment($pdfData,$fileName);    
$bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
$bodyPart-setParts(array($bodyMessage,$attachment));
$transport-getMessage()-setBody($bodyPart);                
$transport-sendMessage(); $inlineTranslation-resume();
```

Comment: Not working in the latest version of Magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-pdf-attachment-not-working-issue-in-magento-2-3-3/
I followed this link and this worked for me.