# How to add pdf in mail in Magento2.4.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.3.4

I tried almost all solutions from the internet but nothing works in magento 2.4 and above.
for pdf attachment in mail

If Anyone knows how to attach pdf in mail. Please share your answer.

Thanks.

Comment: can you check Please :-- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211521/85907 , https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289297/magento-2-3-send-an-email-with-pdf-attachment

Comment: HI @MohitPatel, Those are all not working for 2.4

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298001/82670

Comment: HI @Msquare. Previously i tried this solution with Zend and Laminas but i got the same error Zend/Mime/PartFactory does not exist and error Laminas/Mime/PartFactory does not exist.

Comment: You can check in your Magento vendor folder. Path:  vendor/laminas/laminas-mime/src/Part.php.  The solution works well.